# Displaying keys and values in a multidimensional Laravel object

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I would like to put my keys and values in a collection like this

```
$attributes = [
            ['key' => 'color', 'value' => 'red'],
            ['key' => 'color', 'value' => 'blue'],
            ['key' => 'color', 'value' => 'red'],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 2],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 2],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 3],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 3],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 3],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 3],
            ['key' => 'height', 'value' => (int) 3],
            ['key' => 'color', 'value' => 'red'],
            ['key' => 'material', 'value' => 'iron'],
            ['key' => 'material', 'value' => 'iron'],
            ['key' => 'material', 'value' => 'gold'],
            ['key' => 'material', 'value' => 'gold'],
            ['key' => 'material', 'value' => 'gold'],
        ];
```

I also have the values I receive in the database, saved in a json
Like this

```
 "attributes" => "{"Attribute":[{"Attribute_name":"heigth","Attribute_value":"8"},{"Attribute_name":"color","Attribute_value":"red"},{"Attribute_name":"heigth","Attribute_value":"8"},{"Attribute_name":"heigth","Attribute_value":"2"}]}"
```

I tried to make something like this

```
$attributes = [];

        foreach ($feeds as $feed) {
            array_push($attributes, $feed->attributes);
        }
        $test = collect(json_decode($attributes[0]));
        dd($test);
```

But I will receive something this way

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#696
  #items: array:1 [
    "Attribute" => array:4 [
      0 => {#380
        +"Attribute_name": "height"
        +"Attribute_value": "8"
      }
      1 => {#373
        +"Attribute_name": "color"
        +"Attribute_value": "red"
      }
      2 => {#359
        +"Attribute_name": "height"
        +"Attribute_value": "8"
      }
      3 => {#1315
        +"Attribute_name": "height"
        +"Attribute_value": "2"
      }
    ]
  ]
```

In the end, I would like to somehow push that collection and have the key, value as I have above
Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can try like this

```
 $attributes = '{"Attribute":[{"Attribute_name":"heigth","Attribute_value":"8"},{"Attribute_name":"color","Attribute_value":"red"},{"Attribute_name":"heigth","Attribute_value":"8"},{"Attribute_name":"heigth","Attribute_value":"2"}]}';
      $attributes_array = json_decode($attributes);

      $attributes = [];
      foreach ($attributes_array->Attribute as $key=> $value){ 
          $attributes[$key]['key']=$value->Attribute_name;
          $attributes[$key]['value']=$value->Attribute_value;
      }
      dd($attributes);
```

Desire Results

```
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "key" => "heigth"
    "value" => "8"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "key" => "color"
    "value" => "red"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "key" => "heigth"
    "value" => "8"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "key" => "heigth"
    "value" => "2"
  ]
]
```